# Is it possible let to run in background an installed Android app via code?

Tags: java, android

The title explains itself, when you install an app Android asks you if you want to let it to run in background. I haven't founded something useful to do it via code, I mean, can we do it?

I've been reading and some people say *setComponentEnabledSetting * could be the answer but I'm not really sure.

I can't upload an image 'cause my account is new but [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B68cwDY8DqLIMWVxTm9uc1ZDWEE) is an example what I'm talking about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Android, background operations are done using a `Service`, you can start/stop your service based on the user's preference.

Comment: "when you install an app Android asks you if you want to let it to run in background" -- not generally. What device is this? If it is a SONY, this may be a screen related to their STAMINA mode.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, you're right, not generally, it is an Huawei device, manually I can do it via Batery Settings or Apps Manager but by code no.

@Titus I gonna read about `Service` a little more.